# Dit-on plutôt « Je suis en heure de pause» ou « Je suis sur mon heure de pause »?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

J’entends « pause » au sens de « pause-dîner.

Dit-on mieux:

Je suis en heure de pause, tu peux donc m’appeler.

Je suis sur mon heure de pause, tu peux donc m’appeler.

Je suis en pause, tu peux donc m’appeler.

Si jamais toutes ces propositions vous semblent écrites en mauvais français, n’hésitez pas à m’en proposer de meilleures! Merci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En France, on dit en général:

> *Je suis en pause déjeuner<sup>1</sup>, tu peux m'appeler.*

*Je suis en heure de pause* est possible, mais ça ne s'entend pas trop, ce serait plutôt, *je prends mon heure de pause déjeuner* s'il faut préciser la durée.

Je n'ai jamais entendu *Je suis sur mon heure...*, ce doit être un québécisme.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Contrairement à la Belgique, la Suisse et le Canada qui n'ont pas décalé les noms des heures de repas comme ici.</sub>

Comment: _Je suis sur mon heure de dîner/lunch_, ouais certainement courant au Québec.

Comment: En tant que Français, "Je suis sur mon heure de pause" ne me choque pas, mais je pense qu'on entend plus souvent la constuction suivante "je ferais cela sur mon heure de pause".

Comment: @XouDo L'expression ne me choque pas non plus, mais elle est essentiellement inusitée ici. La première page de recherche de *Je suis sur mon heure* retournée par Google retourne 100 % de sources québécoises si on se limite au sens utilisé dans la question, en excluant donc par exemple *concentrée comme je suis sur mon heure de cours*.